# Cant keep original FileName after Upload

Tags: php, html, file-upload, filenames

I am currently using PHP to **create a file upload system**. I took help from internet and successfully made the project.

But problem was that after upload the **FileName** would change to something complicated. Eg: 5987fff5b3dd83.21913884.

Is there a way to retain the original name after upload. Currently location is in **Localhost** but later I have to upload it to my website.

Code for index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file">
<button type="submit" name="submit">UPLOAD</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Code for upload.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$file = $_FILES['file'];

$fileName = $file['name'];
$fileTmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $file['size'];
$fileError = $file['error'];
$fileType = $file['type'];

$fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

$allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');

if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
    if ($fileError === 0) {
        if ($fileSize < 1000000) {
            $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
            $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
            move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
            echo "OK";
            header("Location: ab.html");
        } else {
            echo "Your file is too big!";
        }
    } else {
        echo "There was an error uploading your file!";
    }
} else {
    echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
}
}
```

Kindly suggest possible way to solve the problem.

Regards

Harsh Bansal

Comment: The original filename is in the $_FILES superglobal.  Please read the PHP manual on the topic of uploading files.  http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are doing is assigning random value to name

```
 $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
```

do this

```
 $fileNameNew = $fileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

comment this line

```
 $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
```

how to comment is

```
// $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
```

you are using uniqid function which will generate new file name.

then add

```
$fileNameNew = $fileName;
```